# How to get gzip from url and convert it into jsonobject in android?

Tags: android, gzip

I have a URL which return a `file.gz`  , i need to get the `json` data from this URL .. how can i do that?
I need the answer of the two steps i should follow
1- get the file from url
2- get the json data from this file

Comment: Post the relevant code snippets that you have tried along with the issues in them.

Comment: i don't know what to write to get the file from url